# Changed vector source in doesn't persist in OpenLayers v4

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to use a radio button to filter features displayed on a map.  I managed to change vector source upon button click.  However it seems that the map automatically renders again with the original vector source at the end and overwrote the updated vector source.

```
var styleCache = {};

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'sla.kml',
    format: new ol.format.KML({
        extractStyles: false
    })
});

var clusters = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Cluster({
        distance: 40,
        source: vectorSource
    }),
    style: function(feature) {
        var size = feature.get('features').length;
        var style = styleCache[size];
        if (!style) {
            style = new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 10,
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: '#fff'
                    }),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: '#3399cc'
                    })
                }),
                text: new ol.style.Text({
                    text: size.toString(),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: '#fff'
                    })
                })
            });
            styleCache[size] = style;
        }
        return style;
    }
});

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
    coordinateformat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
    undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
});

var scalelineControl = new ol.control.ScaleLine();

var zoomSlider = new ol.control.ZoomSlider();

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster, clusters],
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([scalelineControl, zoomSlider]),
    renderer: 'canvas',
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [-11102324.569458216, 4548521.327621765],
        zoom:5
    })
});

var count = 0;
var allFeatures;
function changeFeatures(status) {
    if (count == 0) {
        allFeatures = vectorSource.getFeatures();
    }
    count++;
    // clear all features first, then add them back base on status
    vectorSource.clear();
    if (status === 'all') {
        vectorSource.addFeatures(allFeatures);
    } else {
        var feature, name;
        for (var i = allFeatures.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            feature = allFeatures[i];
            if (feature.get('status') === status) {
                vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
            }
        }
    }
}

vectorSource.on('change', function(evt) {
    var source = evt.target;
    if (source.getState() === 'ready') {
        var numfeatures = source.getFeatures().length;
        console.log("feature count after change event: " + numfeatures);
    }
});
```

The output from console shows:

- feature count after change event: 9    -> original features
- feature count after change event: 0    -> after clear vector source
- feature count after change event: 1    -> after add one qualified feature
- feature count after change event: 9    -> seem to render map again with original vector source (why?)

Why is the map rendered again with the original vector source?  What do I need to do to have the map render with the updated vector source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a source is configured with a `url`, calling `#clear()` on it will trigger a reload.

You can either set a new source on the vector layer (using `ol.layer.Vector#setSource()`), or create your `vectorSource` with an initial configuration without `url`. I'd recommend the former.